# I accidentally pressed X when I was in a different car and I lost my other car

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have an apartment with two car garages and had two cars, but I accidentally pressed X when I was in a different car. Leaving my garage, and my first car was at the Impound, I realized I made the mistake and lost my first car.
But why ain't I allowed to have another car in there now?

Answer (score 1):

If your car was impounded and then destroyed in online mode this would explain why you can't add more vehicles to the garage as destroyed and impounded vehicles still fill a slot until you retrieve them. For online mode you have the 4 options listed below for getting the vehicle back when impounded, although if your vehicle has been destroyed already then you will need to call Mors Mutual to pay to have it replaced.

1. If you have an office you can call your assistant on the phone to pick up the vehicle from the impound for $1000
2. You can wait for it to be destroyed or destroy it by taking out another personal vehicle then call Mors Mutual to have it replaced by insurance
3. You can steal the vehicle from the impound lot marked in purple on the map below which is free but gets the cops after you.
4. You can go to the Mission Row police station marked in red on the map below to pick up a car from the impound after paying a $250 fee. This method also works in story mode as well.

[image]

Sources:
https://www.sportskeeda.com/gta/where-find-impound-gta-5-story-mode [for story mode info]
https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Impound_Garage#Grand_Theft_Auto_Online [For the map and information on online mode]

Comment: When or where is the impound fee paid? Impounded my Oppressor mid-mission and when I went to get it I couldn't find where to pay, but also did not gain wanted level or notice any money taken when I stole it back. Solo in closed friend session, mission involved police (DC heist prep, untraceable weapons).